# React Native file upload with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, react-native

I am building a mobile application using react native with Rails as an API, I have a problem uploading an image I used react-native-image-picker library for uploading camera roll images in IOS and XMLHttRequest for connecting to the API endpoint and for uploading file in Rails I used the default carrierwave setup.

When I try to upload from postman it is working but from react native its not. Below is my code in react native upload request:

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        var source;

        // You can display the image using either:
        //source = {uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data, isStatic: true};

        //Or:
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          source = {uri: response.uri, isStatic: true};
        } else {
          source = {uri: response.uri.replace('file://', ''), isStatic: true};
        }
        var photo = {
          uri: source.uri,
          type: 'image/jpeg',
          name: response.fileName
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var body = new FormData();
        body.append('authToken', token);
        body.append('avatar', photo);

        xhr.open('POST', uri);

        xhr.send(body)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, I used fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest and

Comment: I forgot the Authorization in Headers